# PHP and SQL not Posting

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, post

My PHP code to POST to my SQL on Godaddy's hosting is not working for some reason.. I added debug statements but I'm just not sure why it's not working. It's driving me crazy.

Here's my file named "homepage.php":

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    include('mysql_connection.php');
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (typed) VALUES ('$entry')";
        if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql)) {
            die('Error inserting text.');
        }
    $newentry = "One entry added to the database.";
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" action="homepage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
    <input type="text" name="entry" maxlength="200" />
    <br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="insert" />
</form>
</center>

    <?php echo $newentry?>

</body>
</html>
```

And my database is named "subpost-db" with the table "posts" and a column named "typed" with VARCHAR values.

My SQL connection file is named "mysql-connection.php" and here's the code:

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'subpost-db');
$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);
if (!$dbcon) {
    die('Error connecting to the requested database. ');
}
?>
```

By the way, when I go to mysql-connection.php on my website, the debug message does not pop up.

When I click "insert" after typing something on my form, it reloads homepage.php, where my form is, and only displays the text that says "Error inserting text." but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Shehary only if their submit bears a name attribute for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i missed the input, my bad

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbcon))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Shehary that got rid of the error message, now im just stuck with a blank page but it's still not posting to the column.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry man, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @julian, Fred means that if your submit input has `name=""`

Comment: But he already has a `name="submitted"` which has the value of `true`, so `if(isset($_POST["submitted"]))` condition will still work. I'm pretty sure that the error occurs when establishing his connection (_maybe on his host name, username, password, or database name_) or on his query (_column name, table name, etc._).

Comment: @LoganWayne actually I suggested OP to change this `if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {` to this `if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {` which actually helped to get rid of the error but Fred suggested that if input has name and he is right input submit doesn't has name so he was right too so as I but the problem is somewhere elese

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://pastebin.com/QgELXgAg

Comment: @LoganWayne http://pastebin.com/QgELXgAg

Comment: @Shehary http://pastebin.com/QgELXgAg

Comment: *"expires: in 6 days"* sorry, I won't be around here that long. Error logs?!?

Comment: The problem is very clear db file path is wrong

Comment: @Shehary Yeah I totally agree, but what can I do to fix it? I'm not familiar with paths..

Comment: @Shehary http://imgur.com/MgxYiKb

Comment: @julian the error is this `include(mysql_connection.php)` and file name in picture is `mysql-connection.php` so find the difference

Comment: @Shehary Brb I'm looking for bleach, I'm thirsty. Omg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error from your query so add the correct reporting to the test after the code that issues the query to the database and it will tell you what is wrong.

```
<?php
    // from Fred-ii- comment
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);


    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        include('mysql_connection.php');
        $entry = $_POST['entry'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (typed) VALUES ('$entry')";
        if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql)) {
            die('Error inserting text. ' . mysqli_error($dbcon) );   //<-- changed line
        }
        $newentry = "One entry added to the database.";
    }
?>
```